# local integrability of function

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

The problem asks to show that $G(\xi,\tau)=\frac{1}{2\pi i\tau+4\pi^2|\xi|^2}$ is locally integrable on $\mathbb{R^n\times R}$.

So, any compact set $K$ is inside $B_R(0)\times[-R,R]$ for some $R>0$. Therefore, it suffices to show that the following integral is finite: 
$$\int_{B_R(0)\times[-R,R]}\Big|\frac{1}{2\pi i\tau+4\pi^2|\xi|^2}\Big|=\omega_n\int_{-R}^{R}\int_0^R\Big|\frac{r^{n-1}}{2\pi i\tau+4\pi^2r^2}\Big|dr d\tau$$

It is simple to show that it converges for $n>2$.

So, I am a bit confused about the cases $n=1,2$.

Any hints are welcome!

P.S. $G(\xi,\tau)$ is the Fourier transform of the extended Gaussian kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use different notation and consider a problem without all of those constants floating around. For $(x,y) \in \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^n,$ consider

$$\int_{B(0,1)}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt {x^2+|y|^4}}\,dx\,dy.$$

Letting $x =|y|^2t$ and using symmetry, the above is $2$ times

$$\int_{B(0,1)}\int_{0}^{1/|y|^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt {t^2 + 1}}\,dt\,dy.$$

Now the inner integrand is $\approx 1/(1+t).$ Put that in and then evaluate the inner integral to get

$$\int_{B(0,1)} \ln (1+1/|y|^2)\, dy.$$

In any dimension the last integrand is locally integrable, so we're done with this stripped down version of what you have. I think that's enough to see through the bells and whistles in your problem.